# How do I get rid of this box that opens when logging in using remote desktop?

Tags: 14.04, server, remote-desktop, lxde, xrdp

[This box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwVGG.png) shows up every time I login to Ubuntu using remote desktop. I'm on Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS with the Lubuntu LXDE Desktop (`lubuntu-core`). Is there any way for me to get rid of it?